# Use chrome.app.window.create in a user javascript

Tags: javascript, window, google-chrome-app

window.open works but I wan't to try using the chrome.app method but nothing happens

I downloaded the chrome app samples from https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples and the sample called window-options doesn't work for me either...

If I click on Create Window nothing happens
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/master/samples/window-options/assets/screenshot_1280_800.png

EDIT: tried enabling experimental API's and still not working

Comment: What have samples have you tried?

Comment: Calculator, Hello World and Dart examples works. window-options, clock, and systemInfo doesn't work. Haven't tried all

Comment: The clock example didn't work in the example but this app does work https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/world-clock/lhfiglpmnendbchimlikaeachppfonmm   Anyways, im not making a clock, I just try to open a window with chrome.app.window.create and nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

The samples does seem to work, including the one opening a new window.
What I did wrong was not loading them as extension, I just opened the html in browser.
So I guess I have to make an extension and not a user javascript to do what I wan't to do

Comment: Well, _duh_, high-privilege APIs are not available to web pages. Do note that in case of extensions you probably want `chrome.windows.create()` or `chrome.tabs.create()`. The `windows` one with `type: "popup"` is the closest.